# reading 4 bit blocks from .bin file

Tags: c++

I have a .bin file that has pixel data stored in 4 bit format (i.e each pixel is 4 bits). How can I read data into a C program as 4 bits. Char reads it in 8 bit blocks so if I have a pointer to the start of he file and increment it, it skips a pixel.

Comment: This can be solved with a modest change to your code...

Comment: Maybe, since each byte has 8 bits, you can look at only 1/2 of the byte?

Comment: @DrewDormann: of course if the OP had included some code you could point out where ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any processor which allows you to read from a file in increments of less than one byte (although the number of bits in a byte varies on some processors), and there is no support in C++ for reading chunks less than a byte in size. Assuming 8 bits in a byte, you will need to read a byte and then split it into two pixels.

If your read returned unsigned char c, then

```
sometype pixel1 = c >> 4;
sometype pixel2 = c & 0xf;
```

Comment: Be careful when bit-shifting signed types.  :)

Comment: I made it an unsigned char for simplicity.